# Why was this question protected when no one answered?

Tags: support

Why was this question protected when no one answered? There are no 'thanks' 'me too' answers and my answer was posted today.

[Galaxy Note 1 has become slow after upgrading the phone 4.1.2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42467/galaxy-note-1-has-become-slow-after-upgrading-the-phone-4-1-2/47818#47818)

Comment: Probably because all the "me too" answers got deleted. (I don't have 10k there so I can't see for sure.)

Comment: Community only auto-protects a question after so many answers from low-rep users have been deleted. - *"There are no 'thanks' 'me too' answers and my answer was posted today."* Ummm, *your* answer is one of those...

Comment: @animuson How is my answer one of those when I posted an answer which is to downgrade!? Me too which I mentioned was just an FYI added to the answer!

Comment: @Tony you mean [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42467/galaxy-note-1-has-become-slow-after-upgrading-the-phone-4-1-2/47818#comment64349_42467)? That's not an answer so it was rightfully converted to comment.

Comment: @Sha I didn't know it was converted until I read your comment. So no, my post is not about that.

Comment: @Sha and I don't feel this questions is a duplicate. I know why questions get protected. I am asking about a specific edge case.

Comment: That's not an edge case. In the linked post it says "The system (via the Community user) will automatically protect a question that's had three answers from low-rep users deleted". As Anna said below that's exactly the case so as the title of the banner says "This question already has an answer" in that other question.

Comment: @Sha Yeah that's clear to the users who have 10k rep.

Comment: @Tony not sure what you expect then? In general when you see question protected by Community it means there are at least three deleted answers from low rep users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were 3 deleted answers before you added your own.

As [animuson mentioned in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185571/why-was-this-question-protected-when-no-one-answered#comment568580_185571), questions are automatically protected when they attract too many deleted answers from brand new users.